# Why everything goes above my navbar when I use @extend to display the navbar from another page

Tags: laravel

[image]

So I want to include my navbar to every page. I use @extends in laravel and When I define any html elements, It just goes above the navbar. It does not make sense at all. I write the html elements under the navbar but why does it go on top?????

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
@extends('layout.header')
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
@extends('layout.navbar')
 asdasdsa   


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, you probably looking for `@include` rather than `@extends`, you may be best checking out the docs for blade layouts https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#layouts-using-template-inheritance

You would generally have a base layout that includes other blade templates for say your nav header and footers, and also yields sections so that you can extend the layout in your actual pages and place content where you need it.

Comment: `@extends` is used to define the layout you want to use. So you should only have one in your view code.`@include` renders a partial. However i think a component would be better if the navbar is not hardcoded (to prevent duplicate controller code).